# Getting Value from HTML and storing to variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

I have the following code: http://pastebin.com/61K2J9kR

Can anyone tell me why the value is not getting stored into **dest_x** ? The input in the textbox should be stored into **dest_x** once the **'GO!'** button is clicked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It may be because you have two `onclick` attributes on the same element.

```
<INPUT id="btnMove" type="button" value="GO!" onClick="javascript:var t=setInterval('moveRight()', 80)" onClick="getValue()">
```

You should only have one:

```
<input id="btnMove" type="button" value="GO!" onclick="var t=setInterval('moveRight()', 80); getValue();">
```

You also shouldn't have `javascript:` in the `onclick` event - that was a technique used to place JavaScript in an `href` attribute.

You should also move the retrieval of `dest_x` into your moveRight function:

```
function moveRight() {
    var dest_x = document.getElementById('txtChar').value;
    //...
```

Note that it is `getElementById`, not `getElementByID` - JavaScript is case sensitive.

I have included these changes in an updated version of your script: http://pastebin.com/aX6mXRhg

These changes make things functional - there are other things that you may want to consider later on - but the fixes above should get your going in the meantime.

1. Scoping your functions and variables
2. Attaching the events in JavaScript, rather than HTML attributes
3. Avoid using `eval`